# AVD's configuration is missing a kernal file

Tags: linux, android-sdk

Recently I've migrated from windows to ubuntu, installed Android SDk in Ubuntu 12.10 and created the AVD launched it shows this Error: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernal file, I installed ARM EABI v7a System Image for all the Android 4.X.X. Still it is not allowing me to get the AVD. Help me to spot the issue.

Comment: did  u try restarting after installing ??

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file

Comment: I already referred this page but no use